# Uploading to S3 bucket using missing SessionToken in AWS SDK for .NET

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/uploaddownloaddelete-files-from-aws-s3-using-net-core-api/) on uploading files to the AWS S3 bucket.

The author is using `AppConfiguration` for configuring AWS:

```cs
public class AppConfiguration : IAppConfiguration
{
    // Keep the following details in appsettings.config file or DB or Enivironment variable
    // Get those values from it and assign to the below varibales. Based on the approach , modify the below code.
    public AppConfiguration()
    {
        BucketName = "";
        Region = "";
        AwsAccessKey = "";
        AwsSecretAccessKey = "";
        AwsSessionToken = "";
    }

    public string BucketName { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string AwsAccessKey { get; set; }
    public string AwsSecretAccessKey { get; set; }
    public string AwsSessionToken { get; set; }
}
```

Among others, there's a `AwsSessionToken` property which I don't know how to retrieve/generate.

How can I retrieve a session token?

Comment: That tutorial is very incorrect, you should **never ever ever ever** put literal access keys like that in the configuration-

Comment: Instead download the AWS CLI, type `aws configure` and set up your [shared AWS credentials file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/creds-file.html) (or manually create it) for the .NET SDK to then pick up on automatically.

Comment: Follow Ermiya's advice.  To answer your specific question, Session Tokens are a 3rd part of the credential process that only applies to temporary access tokens.  It doesn't apply if you're using long lived access key.

Comment: Thanks all, I guess I'll find some other tutorial for uploading on s3

Comment: @user1765862 go to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/upload-objects.html, scroll down to the SDK section, select .NET and you should be sorted. It's super easy to upload a file, it doesn't need pages and pages of content ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR: use the [shared AWS credentials file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/creds-file.html) & delete all code related to credentials within your application including the credentials themselves as they are a security risk.**

---

Never, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, *ever* store credentials within application files.

Here is what the [AWS SDK for .NET Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds-warnings-and-guidelines.html) issues important warnings on, for credentials:

> **Do NOT put literal access keys in your application files.** If you do, you create a risk of accidentally exposing your credentials if, for example, you upload the project to a public repository.

> **Do NOT include files that contain credentials in your project area.**

This is pretty much reiterated everywhere [else](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_environment.html) too:

> We recommend that you **never add your AWS access keys directly to the client in any production files**. Many developers have had their account compromised by leaked keys.

---

**Instead, use a method of providing credentials within the [default credentials provider chain for the .NET SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/creds-assign.html) to securely provide credentials to your .NET application.**

It's easier and much cleaner than creating a POCO, or handling credentials within your code.

For local development, I always prefer the [shared AWS credentials file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/creds-file.html), which you can create yourself or use `aws configure` via the AWS CLI to set it up. The AWS SDK will then automatically pick up on the credentials without you needing to specify anything within the code.

Using an AWS credentials file offers the following [benefits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_profiles.html):

- Your projects’ credentials are stored outside of your projects, so
  there is no chance of accidentally committing them into version
  control.
- You can define and name multiple sets of credentials in one place.
- You can easily reuse the same credentials among projects.
- Other AWS SDKs and tools support, this same credentials file. This
  allows you to reuse your credentials with other tools.

Just please don't hardcode credentials whatever you do.

---

FYI: session tokens are used to validate temporary AWS credentials. Your access key ID & secret access key are permanent methods of authenticating until they are deactivated/deleted, so you don't need to worry about session tokens at all.

Comment: Credential files are good for workstations.  If you are planning on running the code on EC2, ECS or Lambda, they will have their credentials handled automatically if you follow this advice and don't do anything explicit with the credentials.